# How can I start CSS3 Animations at a specific spot?

Tags: javascript, css, webkit, css-animations

I'm using CSS3 Animations, and I want to be able to move to a specific spot in the animation.  For instance, if the CSS looks like this (and pretend that I used all the proper prefixes):

```
@keyframes fade_in_out_anim {
  0% { opacity: 0; }
  25% { opacity: 1; }
  75% { opacity: 1; }
  100% { opacity: 0; }
}
#fade_in_out {
  animation: fade_in_out_anim 5s;
}
```

then I would like to be able to stop the animation, and move it to the 50% mark.  I guess that the ideal JavaScript would look something like this:

```
var style = document.getElementById('fade_in_out').style;
style.animationPlayState = 'paused';

// Here comes the made up part...
style.animation.moveTo('50%'); // Or alternately...
style.animationPlayPosition = '50%';
```

Does anyone know of a way to make this happen (hopefully in Webkit)?

Comment: Can you provide more information on what you're goal is? Because if you just want to start an animation at the half-way point, I'd recommend two animations, one starting at 50% and one the full effect, then choose between them using classes.

Comment: I want to be able to create a slider or touch interaction that will let the user scrub along an animation. I've settled on breaking the animation into stages until I find out how to do what I need.

Answer (score 36):

We can use the `animation-delay` property. Usually it delays animation for some time, and, if you set `animation-delay: 2s;`, animation will start two seconds after you applied the animation to the element. But, you also can use it to force it to start playing animation with a specific time-shift by using a negative value:

```
.element-animation{
animation: animationFrames ease 4s;
animation-delay: -2s;
}
```

http://default-value.com/blog/2012/10/start-css3-animation-from-specified-time-frame/

Comment: This should be the selected answer.  It's easy to implement and is clear.

Comment: except then you cannot delay the start

Answer (score 0):

1. Get the animation object [affecting the element](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/getAnimations)
2. Get it's [duration](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/AnimationEffect/getTiming#duration)
3. Set the Animation object's [currentTime](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Animation/currentTime) to half of the `duration` value (since you want to set the progress to 50%)

```js
let anim = fade_in_out.getAnimations()[0];
let duration = anim.effect.getTiming().duration;  
anim.currentTime = duration / 2;
```