# How to Make Javascript Date and CSS3 Animations work together?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I need to connect the CSS3 transitions to be aligned with the current time in the Javascript clock.  What does this mean? When the clock is at 30 seconds, the border radius of the clock should be turned half blue and half red.  The change progresses for every second that passes.

I currently have created a Javascript clock that is working great and posted below.  It's one of those 5 o'clock somewhere ones.

I have the CSS3 transitions circulating correctly in look and feel, but it isn't synced up to the Javascript clock.  Does anyone know how to do this?

Here is the fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/LMo/85ePP/3/

```
function updateClock ( ) {
  var currentTime = new Date ( );
  var currentHoursRaw = currentTime.getHours ( );
  var currentHours = currentTime.getHours ( );
  var currentMinutes = currentTime.getMinutes ( );
  var currentSeconds = currentTime.getSeconds ( );

  // Pad the minutes and seconds with leading zeros, if required
  currentMinutes = ( currentMinutes < 10 ? "0" : "" ) + currentMinutes;
  currentSeconds = ( currentSeconds < 10 ? "0" : "" ) + currentSeconds;

  // Compose the string for display
  var currentTimeString = "5" + ":" + currentMinutes + ":" + currentSeconds;

    if(currentHoursRaw == 1) {
     $("#time").html(currentTimeString + "<br/>" +"<span>Area '8'</span>");
     //target iframe.attribute replace with the other area
    } 
    if(currentHoursRaw == 2) {
     $("#time").html(currentTimeString + "<br/>" + "<span>Area '7'</span>");
    } 
    if(currentHoursRaw == 3) {
     $("#time").html(currentTimeString + "<br/>" + "<span>Area '6'</span>");
    } 
    if(currentHoursRaw == 4) {
     $("#time").html(currentTimeString + "<br/>" + "<span>Area '5'</span>");
    } 
    if(currentHoursRaw == 5) {
     $("#time").html(currentTimeString + "<br/>" + "<span>Area '4'</span>");
    } 
    if(currentHoursRaw == 6) {
     $("#time").html(currentTimeString + "<br/>" + "<span>Area '3'</span>");
    } 
    if(currentHoursRaw == 7) {
     $("#time").html(currentTimeString + "<br/>" + "<span>Area '2'</span>");
    } 
    if(currentHoursRaw == 8) {
     $("#time").html(currentTimeString + "<br/>" + "<span>Area '1'</span>");
    } 
    if(currentHoursRaw == 9) {
     $("#time").html(currentTimeString + "<br/>" + "<span>Area 'UTC'</span>");
    } 
    if(currentHoursRaw == 10) {
     $("#time").html(currentTimeString + "<br/>" + "<span>Area '-1'</span>");
    } 
    if(currentHoursRaw == 11) {
     $("#time").html(currentTimeString + "<br/>" + "<span>Area '-2'</span>");
    } 
    if(currentHoursRaw == 12) {
     $("#time").html(currentTimeString + "<br/>" + "<span>Area '-3'</span>");
    } 
    if(currentHoursRaw == 13) {
     $("#time").html(currentTimeString + "<br/>" + "<span>Area '-4'</span>");
    } 
    if(currentHoursRaw == 14) {
     $("#time").html(currentTimeString + "<br/>" + "<span>Area '-5'</span>");
    } 
    if(currentHoursRaw == 15) {
     $("#time").html(currentTimeString + "<br/>" + "<span>Area '-6'</span>");
    } 
    if(currentHoursRaw == 16) {
     $("#time").html(currentTimeString + "<br/>" + "<span>Area '-7'</span>");
    } 
    if(currentHoursRaw == 17) {
     $("#time").html(currentTimeString + "<br/>" + "<span>Area '-8'</span>");
    } 
    if(currentHoursRaw == 18) {
     $("#time").html(currentTimeString + "<br/>" + "<span>Area '-9'</span>");
    } 
    if(currentHoursRaw == 19) {
     $("#time").html(currentTimeString + "<br/>" + "<span>Area '-10/+14'</span>");
    } 
    if(currentHoursRaw == 20) {
     $("#time").html(currentTimeString + "<br/>" + "<span>Area '-11/+13'</span>");
    } 
    if(currentHoursRaw == 21) {
     $("#time").html(currentTimeString + "<br/>" + "<span>Area '12'</span>");
    } 
    if(currentHoursRaw == 22) {
     $("#time").html(currentTimeString + "<br/>" + "<span>Area '11'</span>");
    } 
    if(currentHoursRaw == 23) {
     $("#time").html(currentTimeString + "<br/>" + "<span>Area '10'</span>");
    } 
    if(currentHoursRaw == 24) {
     $("#time").html(currentTimeString + "<br/>" + "<span>Area '9'</span>");
    }
}

$(document).ready(function(){
  setInterval('updateClock()', 1000);
});
```

CSS Transitions :

```
.timerSize4 {
  -webkit-animation-iteration-count: infinite;
  animation-iteration-count: infinite;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 7;
  width: 433px;
  height: 433px;
  border-radius: 50%; 
}

#timer4 {
  opacity: .7;
  top: 24%;
  left: 37%;
  background-color: #99182d;

/*  Plays an animation with the same speed from beginning to end */
  -webkit-animation-timing-function: steps(1);
  animation-timing-function: steps(1);

  -webkit-animation-duration: 60s;
  animation-duration: 60s;

  -webkit-animation-name: timerBGChange;
  animation-name: timerBGChange;
  z-index: -1;
}

/* deals with the right half ot he circle */
#timer4a {
  background-color: #02266e;
  /* Clip property lets you specify a rectangle to clip an absolutey position element*/
  clip:rect(0px,216.5px,433px,0px);
  -webkit-animation-timing-function: linear,steps(1);
  animation-timing-function: linear,steps(1);

  -webkit-animation-duration: 30s,60s;
  animation-duration: 30s,60s;

  -webkit-animation-name: timerRotate,timerBGChange2;
  animation-name: timerRotate,timerBGChange2;
  z-index: 7;
}

/* deals with second half of circle */
#timer4b {
  background-color: #02266e;
  clip:rect(0,433px,433px,216.5px);
  -webkit-animation-timing-function: steps(1);
  animation-timing-function: steps(1);

  -webkit-animation-duration: 60s;
  animation-duration: 60s;

  -webkit-animation-name: timerBG1;
  animation-name: timerBG1; 
  z-index: 7;
}

/* blue on right side unil it hits 30 */
#timer4c {
  background-color: #02266e;
  clip:rect(0px,216.5px,433px,0px);
  -webkit-animation-timing-function: steps(1);
  animation-timing-function: steps(1);

  -webkit-animation-duration: 60s;
  animation-duration: 60s;

  -webkit-animation-name: timerBG2;
  animation-name: timerBG2;
  z-index: 7;
}

@-webkit-keyframes timerBGChange {
  0% { background-color: #02266e; }    
  50% { background-color: #99182d; }    
}

@-webkit-keyframes timerRotate {
  0% { -webkit-transform:rotate(0); }
  100% { -webkit-transform:rotate(360deg); }    
}
@-webkit-keyframes timerBGChange2 {
  0% { background-color: #99182d; }
  50% { background-color: #02266e; }    
}
@-webkit-keyframes timerBG1 {
  0% { opacity: 0; background-color: #99182d; } 
  25% { opacity: 1; }
  50% { opacity: 0; background-color: #02266e; } 
  75% { opacity: 1; }
}
@-webkit-keyframes timerBG2 {
  0% { opacity: 1; } 
  25% { opacity: 0; background-color: #99182d; }  
  50% { opacity: 1; } 
  75% { opacity: 0; background-color: #02266e; }
}

@keyframes timerBGChange {
  0% { background-color: #02266e; }    
  50% { background-color: #99182d; }    
}

@keyframes timerRotate {
  0% { transform:rotate(0); }
  100% { transform:rotate(360deg); }    
}
@keyframes timerBGChange2 {
  0% { background-color: #99182d; }
  50% { background-color: #02266e; }    
}
@keyframes timerBG1 {
  0% { opacity: 0; background-color: #99182d; } 
  25% { opacity: 1; }
  50% { opacity: 0; background-color: #02266e; } 
  75% { opacity: 1; }
}
@keyframes timerBG2 {
  0% { opacity: 1; } 
  25% { opacity: 0; background-color: #99182d; }  
  50% { opacity: 1; } 
  75% { opacity: 0; background-color: #02266e; }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Can you post a http://jsfiddle.net/ example with the code?
The best option to achieve what you want is to add the necessary class (`.timerSize4`) that triggers the animation from the javascript function that drives the clock. 
You can then add a  class with the `animation-delay` that syncs the 2 clocks.

Something like `$("<style>.timerSize4 {animation-delay:"+theNegativeTimerDelayInMs+" ms;}</style>").appendTo("body")`

More info on animation-delay can be found here:
http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_animation-delay.asp
or
[How can I start CSS3 Animations at a specific spot?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10540720/how-can-i-start-css3-animations-at-a-specific-spot)

This is an working example:
http://jsfiddle.net/85ePP/2/

**UPDATE**: This are the changes (i also changed the document ready function):

```
    function startTimer(){

    var currentTime = new Date();
    var currentSeconds = currentTime.getSeconds();
    var currentMs = -currentTime.getMilliseconds()-currentSeconds*1000;
    $("<style>.timerSize4 {animation-delay: "+currentMs+"ms;-webkit-animation-delay: "+currentMs+"ms;}</style>").appendTo("head");
    updateClock();
    setInterval(function(){updateClock();}, 1000);
}
$(document).ready(function(){
    startTimer();
});
```

**UPDATE:** It worked on Chrome. In firefox it had a space between the seconds and the little s and didn't consider it valid css. It works now. I also changed from seconds to milliseconds so it is more accurate.

**UPDATE:** This is the full example that works for me:

```
 <style>
 /* CLOCK */

.clock-container {
  left: 29.5%;
  position: absolute;
  top: 8%;
  z-index: 20;
}

#clock {
  background:rgba(2,38,110,.95);
    border-radius: 50%;
    height: 22.1875em;
  margin-top: 48%;
  text-align: center;
  text-transform: uppercase;
    width: 22.1875em;
  left: 48%;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 10;
}

#time {
  font-family: 'Gotham-Black';
  font-size:60px;
  letter-spacing: 3px;
  text-align: center;
  padding-top:138px;
  z-index: 10;
}

span {
  display: inline;
  margin-top: 10px;
  font-family: 'Gotham-Medium';
  font-size: 16px;
}


/*CODE FROM BEN'S PURE CSS CLOCK
http://lab.thisisbensblog.com/purecssclock/
*/

.timerSize4 {
  -webkit-animation-iteration-count: infinite;
  animation-iteration-count: infinite;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 7;
  width: 433px;
  height: 433px;
  border-radius: 50%; 
}

#timer4 {
  opacity: .7;
  top: 24%;
  left: 37%;
  background-color: #99182d;

/*  Plays an animation with the same speed from beginning to end */
  -webkit-animation-timing-function: steps(1);
  animation-timing-function: steps(1);

  -webkit-animation-duration: 60s;
  animation-duration: 60s;

  -webkit-animation-name: timerBGChange;
  animation-name: timerBGChange;
  z-index: -1;
}

/* deals with the right half ot he circle */
#timer4a {
  background-color: #02266e;
  /* Clip property lets you specify a rectangle to clip an absolutey position element*/
  clip:rect(0px,216.5px,433px,0px);
  -webkit-animation-timing-function: linear,steps(1);
  animation-timing-function: linear,steps(1);

  -webkit-animation-duration: 30s,60s;
  animation-duration: 30s,60s;

  -webkit-animation-name: timerRotate,timerBGChange2;
  animation-name: timerRotate,timerBGChange2;
  z-index: 7;
}

/* deals with second half of circle */
#timer4b {
  background-color: #02266e;
  clip:rect(0,433px,433px,216.5px);
  -webkit-animation-timing-function: steps(1);
  animation-timing-function: steps(1);

  -webkit-animation-duration: 60s;
  animation-duration: 60s;

  -webkit-animation-name: timerBG1;
  animation-name: timerBG1; 
  z-index: 7;
}

/* blue on right side unil it hits 30 */
#timer4c {
  background-color: #02266e;
  clip:rect(0px,216.5px,433px,0px);
  -webkit-animation-timing-function: steps(1);
  animation-timing-function: steps(1);

  -webkit-animation-duration: 60s;
  animation-duration: 60s;

  -webkit-animation-name: timerBG2;
  animation-name: timerBG2;
  z-index: 7;
}

@-webkit-keyframes timerBGChange {
  0% { background-color: #02266e; }    
  50% { background-color: #99182d; }    
}

@-webkit-keyframes timerRotate {
  0% { -webkit-transform:rotate(0); }
  100% { -webkit-transform:rotate(360deg); }    
}
@-webkit-keyframes timerBGChange2 {
  0% { background-color: #99182d; }
  50% { background-color: #02266e; }    
}
@-webkit-keyframes timerBG1 {
  0% { opacity: 0; background-color: #99182d; } 
  25% { opacity: 1; }
  50% { opacity: 0; background-color: #02266e; } 
  75% { opacity: 1; }
}
@-webkit-keyframes timerBG2 {
  0% { opacity: 1; } 
  25% { opacity: 0; background-color: #99182d; }  
  50% { opacity: 1; } 
  75% { opacity: 0; background-color: #02266e; }
}

@keyframes timerBGChange {
  0% { background-color: #02266e; }    
  50% { background-color: #99182d; }    
}

@keyframes timerRotate {
  0% { transform:rotate(0); }
  100% { transform:rotate(360deg); }    
}
@keyframes timerBGChange2 {
  0% { background-color: #99182d; }
  50% { background-color: #02266e; }    
}
@keyframes timerBG1 {
  0% { opacity: 0; background-color: #99182d; } 
  25% { opacity: 1; }
  50% { opacity: 0; background-color: #02266e; } 
  75% { opacity: 1; }
}
@keyframes timerBG2 {
  0% { opacity: 1; } 
  25% { opacity: 0; background-color: #99182d; }  
  50% { opacity: 1; } 
  75% { opacity: 0; background-color: #02266e; }
}
 </style>
 <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
 <script>

function updateClock ( ) {
  var currentTime = new Date ( );

  var currentHoursRaw = currentTime.getHours ( );
  var currentHours = currentTime.getHours ( );
  var currentMinutes = currentTime.getMinutes ( );
  var currentSeconds = currentTime.getSeconds ( );

  // Pad the minutes and seconds with leading zeros, if required
  currentMinutes = ( currentMinutes < 10 ? "0" : "" ) + currentMinutes;
  currentSeconds = ( currentSeconds < 10 ? "0" : "" ) + currentSeconds;

  // Compose the string for display
  var currentTimeString = "5" + ":" + currentMinutes + ":" + currentSeconds;

  if(currentHoursRaw == 1) {
     $("#time").html(currentTimeString + "<br/>" +"<span>Area '8'</span>");
    } 
    if(currentHoursRaw == 2) {
     $("#time").html(currentTimeString + "<br/>" + "<span>Area '7'</span>");
    } 
    if(currentHoursRaw == 3) {
     $("#time").html(currentTimeString + "<br/>" + "<span>Area '6'</span>");
    } 
    if(currentHoursRaw == 4) {
     $("#time").html(currentTimeString + "<br/>" + "<span>Area '5'</span>");
    } 
    if(currentHoursRaw == 5) {
     $("#time").html(currentTimeString + "<br/>" + "<span>Area '4'</span>");
    } 
    if(currentHoursRaw == 6) {
     $("#time").html(currentTimeString + "<br/>" + "<span>Area '3'</span>");
    } 
    if(currentHoursRaw == 7) {
     $("#time").html(currentTimeString + "<br/>" + "<span>Area '2'</span>");
    } 
    if(currentHoursRaw == 8) {
     $("#time").html(currentTimeString + "<br/>" + "<span>Area '1'</span>");
    } 
    if(currentHoursRaw == 9) {
     $("#time").html(currentTimeString + "<br/>" + "<span>Area 'UTC'</span>");  
    } 
    if(currentHoursRaw == 10) {
     $("#time").html(currentTimeString + "<br/>" + "<span>Area '-1'</span>");
    } 
    if(currentHoursRaw == 11) {
     $("#time").html(currentTimeString + "<br/>" + "<span>Area '-2'</span>");
    } 
    if(currentHoursRaw == 12) {
     $("#time").html(currentTimeString + "<br/>" + "<span>Area '-3'</span>");
    } 
    if(currentHoursRaw == 13) {
     $("#time").html(currentTimeString + "<br/>" + "<span>Area '-4'</span>");
    } 
    if(currentHoursRaw == 14) {
     $("#time").html(currentTimeString + "<br/>" + "<span>Area '-5'</span>");
    } 
    if(currentHoursRaw == 15) {
     $("#time").html(currentTimeString + "<br/>" + "<span>Area '-6'</span>");
    } 
    if(currentHoursRaw == 16) {
     $("#time").html(currentTimeString + "<br/>" + "<span>Area '-7'</span>");
    } 
    if(currentHoursRaw == 17) {
     $("#time").html(currentTimeString + "<br/>" + "<span>Area '-8'</span>");
    } 
    if(currentHoursRaw == 18) {
     $("#time").html(currentTimeString + "<br/>" + "<span>Area '-9'</span>");
    } 
    if(currentHoursRaw == 19) {
     $("#time").html(currentTimeString + "<br/>" + "<span>Area '-10/+14'</span>");
    } 
    if(currentHoursRaw == 20) {
     $("#time").html(currentTimeString + "<br/>" + "<span>Area '-11/+13'</span>");
    } 
    if(currentHoursRaw == 21) {
     $("#time").html(currentTimeString + "<br/>" + "<span>Area '12'</span>");
    } 
    if(currentHoursRaw == 22) {
     $("#time").html(currentTimeString + "<br/>" + "<span>Area '11'</span>");
    } 
    if(currentHoursRaw == 23) {
     $("#time").html(currentTimeString + "<br/>" + "<span>Area '10'</span>");
    } 
    if(currentHoursRaw == 24) {
     $("#time").html(currentTimeString + "<br/>" + "<span>Area '9'</span>");
    }
}
function startTimer(){

    var currentTime = new Date ( );
    var currentSeconds = currentTime.getSeconds();
    var currentMs = -currentTime.getMilliseconds()-currentSeconds*1000;
    $("<style>.timerSize4 {animation-delay: "+currentMs+"ms; -webkit-animation-delay: "+currentMs+"ms;}</style>").appendTo("head");
    //$(".clock-container>.timerSize4").attr("id","timer4");
    updateClock();
    setInterval(function(){updateClock();}, 1000);
}
$(document).ready(function(){
    startTimer();
});

</script>
 </head>
<body>
<div class="clock-container"> 
    <div id="clock">
        <p id="time"></p>
    </div>
    <div id="timer4" class="timerSize4">
        <div id="timer4a" class="timerSize4"></div>
        <div id="timer4b" class="timerSize4"></div>
        <div id="timer4c" class="timerSize4"></div>
    </div>
</div><!-- clock container -->
</body>
```

Comment: Here is the fiddle. For some reason, I can't get the clock to load in the fiddle - not sure of all of the settings. http://jsfiddle.net/LMo/85ePP/1/

Comment: There is an working example with sync in my answer(at the end)

Comment: It's weird because there isn't even a delay when I put it in my code... it just starts the CSS automatically. I used the new code you posted above!

Comment: It is starting automatically, but it starts from the correct position. If it doesn't start at the correct position, please provide your browser and system. I've tested with chrome 32 and Firefox 25.0.1 (both work great). In opera it doesn't work. In safari it works buggy (even your example)

Comment: I am in Chrome. It starts at the very top every time.